# What abilities can change a class dominant stat in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class

I noticed some abilities allow you to change the main stat used by a class, like:

**Sorcerer:**

- Empyreal version of the Celestial bloodline: use Wis instead of Cha (Ultimate Magic)
- Sage version of the Arcana bloodline: use Int instead of Cha (Ultimate Magic)

**Gunslinger:**

- Mysterious Hero archetype: use Cha instead of Wis (Ultimate Combat)
- Mechanist archetype: use Int instead of Wis (The Secrets of Tactical Archetypes)

So the question is: Are there some equivalents for other classes? Feats, archetypes, even equipment? (In Pathfinder sources, no DD3.5)

Comment: Do you have any limit on acceptable sources, or are you open to all Pathfinder and Pathfinder-compatable sources?

Comment: Sooy, didn't see that comment. If possible, Pathfinder only. I try to limit the DD3.5 stuff as much as possible

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Here](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?t=125732) is a comprehensive "X stat to Y ability" thread updated for 3.5 and pathfinder, with sources and editions listed.

As it says:

> This is a complete rework of old and very much used thread. Someone tried to update it while back, but then pretty much abandoned it rather then hunting down all off the correct book and page number references. There's also a useful re-post over at [brilliant gameologist](http://brilliantgameologists.com/boards/index.php?topic=215.0). But my post is nice enough to put into sortable charts for you.
>
> A frequent build problem is that at mid-high levels, it's likely that your character will only have one or two high attributes, because you have limited bonus attribute points from levels and limited treasure to buy attribute boosting items. Thus it's in your best interest to derive as many bonuses as possible from as few attributes as possible. So the purpose of this post is to compile a list of everything that provides a bonus to anything derived from any attribute.